# Passing instances of classes between activitys

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-intent

If I got class A and class B, class A act as a menu with 2 buttons one to connect one to login. When I press connect i run this method:

```
    private void connect(){
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
    connection_class = new ConnectionClass();
    connection_class.run();
        }
    };t1.start();
}
```

which calls my ConnectionClass which does this in the constructor:

```
    public ConnectionClass(){
        socket = new Socket("address", port);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
}
```

works great im connected to the server and press login which does (without the onClick stuff):

```
        connection_class.MethodToWriteToServer("CommandThatLogsMeIn");     
        Intent i = new Intent().setClass(v.getContext(), Class.class);          
        startActivity(i);
```

This works fine but when im in Class B I want to use the same instance of it. I could just do a new thread and instance of the class but that would defeat the purpose of the start menu and require me to log in once more.

Is it somehow possible to pass the instance as a parameter to the activity when starting it or whats the android way of doing it?

As a sidenote I dont really NEED the menu but ive got some spare time before the assignment is due and thought I might aswell try it.

Comment: Using the same background task from different places sounds like a great place to use a Service :) Apart from that you could use a Singleton that holds the Thread. Should work since all Activities of an Application are in the same Process by default.

Comment: Yea I guess it would thing is I really dont know how to use a service, but I guess ill have to look into it, oh why couldnt it be as simple as C# :p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just finished a project like this yesterday.

For example you have this connection manager, called `WebService`:

```
// singleton class
public class WebService {

    private static WebService instance;

    private WebService() {}

    public static WebService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new WebService();
        return instance;
    }// getInstance()

    public void login() {};
    public void getFeeds() {};
    public void logout() {};
}
```

Then you can put it in an base activity like this:

```
public class WebServiceActivity extends Activity {

    private final WebService fWebService = WebService.getInstance();

    protected WebService ws() { return fWebService; }
}
```

Then, you have two activities, `LoginActivity` and `WorkingActivity`:

```
public class LoginActivity extends WebServiceActivity {

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                ws().login();

                // start WorkingActivity if logging in ok
            } catch (...) { ... }
        }
    });
}

public class WorkingActivity extends WebServiceActivity {

    buttonGetFeeds.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ws().getFeeds();
        }
    });

    buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ws().logout();
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Anyway, there are many approaches. The one above is mine. Hope it helps you  :-)

Comment: You end up having different instances of `WebService` for different Activities since each does `fWebService = new WebService();`

Comment: Thanks zapl, I forgot `WebService` is singleton class. I'll fix it.

Comment: Dude your a total lifesaver this works great, just made a thread out of my constructor and added some of this and now it works great as far as I can tell though I havent had a chance to test everything yet. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I am still don't sure if this is the correct way or not. But I prefer to use a static instance of the class like this:

```
// Create this class just once
public class MediaManager {
    public static MediaManager instance;

    public MediaManager() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void addNewImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
          //....
    }
}
```

//

```
public class AnotherClass {
      public void doSomething() {
          MediaManager.instance.addNewImage(..);
      }
}
```

If somebody know a better way of using Manager Classes please make comment.

Comment: you overwrite `MediaManager.instance` every time you call `... = new MediaManager()` that way you don't get a single static instance. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Traditional_simple_way how you could do it.

Comment: As I comment on my answer you should create MediaManager just one... Alternatively you can use a static method to get instance and check if it is null...